# how to use diff_drive_controller

Tags: ros, diff-drive-controller, nodes, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros_control, ros_controllers, and diff_drive_controller under ROS indigo. however, I am having issues getting the diff_drive_controller node to rosrun.

normally i can tab complete the node executable (e.g rosrun joy joy_node). however, diff drive does not allow autocomplete, and doesn't seem to have an executable. perhaps I have missed something that needs to be set up, but i've read the wiki page a few times and haven't found anything outstanding that would seem to break the install.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196906/how-to-use-diff_drive_controller/) by [Fullmetal99012](https://answers.ros.org/users/20597/fullmetal99012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`diff_drive_controller` is not a node, it is a `controller_manager` plugin. In order to use it, there should be a ros node with a `controller_manager` managing your robot's resources. There are out-of-the-box plugins for doing this in Gazebo (see the `gazebo_ros_control` package), while if you want to have this running on real hardware you'll need to expose your robot to ros_control first.

You can find a high-level overview of ros_control in the ROSCON 2014 program. It's the second talk [here](http://roscon.ros.org/2014/program/).

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M.Ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/25294/m.ahmed/) on 2016-02-26**:
hi Adolfo Rodriguez T .. i already use diff_drive_controller in my simulation it works good. But now i want to implement it on real robot.i don't know how i use it with real robot because i want to publish cmd_vel to real robot and i don't know how to makr driver for this.please help me. on ros wiki

**Comment by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) on 2018-03-30**:
hi Adolfo,
how is the diff_drive_controller interface with the ros_control? is there some place more clarity can be gained regarding this?